# Sublime Text 2. How do I create project for Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, sublimetext2

How do I create a project in Sublime text that can handle compiling and linking Objective-C files?

I can build and run a **single** objective-c file. I am pulling my hair out trying to compile and link multiple files. Is a project file the answer? I'm stumped.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what advantages do you get by using subl over XCode for Obj-C? I love subl for web, but never considered it for Obj-C. My initial reaction is to say just use XCode for the sake of your hair. But, I'm intrigued.

Comment: A project file in Sublime Text doesn't have anything to do with how builds are performed. In fact Sublime Text, being primarily a text editor and not a full-blown IDE, doesn't have a build system built in. You could use something like a `Makefile` that you run from within Sublime, but you'll have a much easier time using a dedicated Objective-C IDE like Xcode instead.

Comment: Hi Corey. I am using ST2 for a class I am teaching and I am trying for a very simple minimal dev setup. I am not building iOS apps. I am just building "headless" executables in Objective-C.

Comment: Hi rpowell. Is there no way to tell ST2 something of the form: clang -o runme foo.m bar.m? That is literally all I need. I can't have my students writing Makefiles. They would freak out. Poor babies.

Comment: You may wish to look at [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/). I also prefer Sublime Text to almost any other editor, but for Objective-C, CodeRunner will do a better job at the clang options and such.

Comment: Hi Christian. But can CodeRunner link multiple .m files? I just grabbed it from the App Store and I have exactly the same problem as I have with ST2. How do I link my class files - multiple .m files - into a single executable? Sigh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A project file is useful for organizing all your files, and I definitely recommend using them for each of your projects, but a [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) will do what you're looking for here. These are very flexible and powerful systems, especially when you take full advantage of the options and variables listed in the [Build System Reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html). A fairly simple example to compile (and optionally run) a single file is below (modified from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chendo/4398077) for semi-unique output file names):

```json
{
  "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "clang -lobjc -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon -o /tmp/${file_name}_sublime_build $file"],
  "file_regex": "^(.*?):([0-9]+):([0-9]+): (.*)",
  "selector": "source.objc",
  "variants": [
    {
      "name": "Run",
      "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "clang -lobjc -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon -o /tmp/${file_name}_sublime_build $file && /tmp/${file_name}_sublime_build"]
    }
  ]
}
```

For multiple class files, probably the best option is to put together a simple [`Makefile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefiles.html) and use Sublime's built-in `Make` build system:

```
{
    "cmd": ["make"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder:${file_path}}}",
    "selector": "source.makefile",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Clean",
            "cmd": ["make", "clean"]
        }
    ]
}
```

This way, you don't need to have a customized `.sublime-build` file for each project (although you might be able to get away with it if they're similar enough), all you'd need to do is create a `Makefile`, set the appropriate project variables, and you're good to go.

Good luck!